# Difference between syntax for inheritance in java and xna(c#)

Tags: c#, java, xna

Currently I'm working on translating a project I made in java, had a quick question regarding using a super class/sub class. Basically, in the java project, I have this in the constructor:

```
public ShipSub(MainGame game, String reference, int x, int y)
{
    super(reference,x,y);
    this.game=game; 
}
```

The part that I'm having issues with is the super(reference,x,y)- what is the correct way to do that in xna? I'm aware that base is used instead of super, but I tried using base the same way I used super in the java code and it didn't work. The parameters for the super class are the same(this project is already finished in java so everything is working how I want) I'm using xna gamepoint 4.0, if that makes any difference.

Thanks.

Comment: I would *strongly* advise against learning C# via XNA. I suggest you learn the basics of C# in a more friendly environment - ideally console apps. I'd also advise you to learn C# from a book, rather than just copying Java over and trying to tweak it until it compiles. You'll end up with *really* nasty code that way.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class ShipSub : SomeBaseClass
{
    private MainGame game;

    public ShipSub(MainGame game, String reference, int x, int y)
        : base(game, reference, x, y)
    {
        this.game = game;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public ShipSub(MainGame game, String reference, int x, int y) : base(reference,x,y)
{
    this.game=game; 
}
```

Assuming the base class has the constructor with `(String reference, int x, int y)`.

Answer (score 1):

`super()` in Java is just a call to the parent class.  A programmatic example of this would be:

```
public class ShipSub : BaseClass // Base class would be what you call `super()` on
{
   private MainGame game;

   public ShipSub(MainGame mainGame, String reference, int x, int y) 
      : base(reference, x, y)
   {
      this.mainGame = game;
   }
}
```

Something to note, the call to `base/super` can be made without parameters as well, but in your case, you would need to add them.